# Steam says that I need to buy the game again

Tags: steam

I purchased and installed Assassin's Creed 4. It wasn't working. Then when I logged out and logged back in I couldn't get my serial code. After changing my password I came back into my steam to find that all of my friends are gone and that I have to purchase Assassin's Creed again. It says that I have installed it but I cannot play it because i have to buy it again. I did purchase it and I got an email saying so.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Steam support https://support.steampowered.com/?

Answer (score 5):

It totally sounds like you logged in with another account ("it says buy the game", "my friends are lost").

Please logout from your steam account and login to the correct one.

You can see your correct steam username in a receipt (Assassin's Creed 4's receipt in this case), for example mine is ardaozkal, and in a receipt I got through mail, it looks like this: 
[image: Part of receipt]